# Binding two HTML tags together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

$scope.wales_total = function(){
        $select_7 = parseInt($(".select_7 strong").html().replace(',' , ''));
        console.log($select_7);
        $welsh_total = Number($select_7 ||0);
        return $welsh_total;
};



$scope.scotland_total = function(){
        $select_8 = parseInt($(".select_8 strong").html().replace(',' , ''));
        $total = Number($select_8 ||0);
        return $total;
};

$scope.ireland_total = function(){
        $select_9 = parseInt($(".select_9 strong").html().replace(',' , ''));
        $total = Number($select_9 ||0);
        return $total;
};

$scope.totals_test = $(".total").html();
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-switch-when="NHS Wales Health Board">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <form>
                                        <label class="pull-left">Health Board</label>
                                        <select ui-select2 class="form-control select_2nd" ng-model="selectedOption_7" ng-options="data as data.displayName for data in wales_data"></select>
                                        <div class="population_estimate_wrapper">
                                            <p class="population_estimate">Population Estimate</p>
                                            <div class="population_estimate_box" ng-model="selectedOption_7">
                                                <p class="hidden select_7"><strong>{{selectedOption_7.value}}</strong></p>
                                                <p class="total" ng-model="total">{{wales_total()}}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div ng-switch-when="NHS Scotland Health Board">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="pull-left">Health Board</label>
                                            <select ui-se-lect2 class="form-control select_2nd" ng-model="selectedOption_8" ng-options="data as data.displayName for data in scotland_data"></select>
                                            <div class="population_estimate_wrapper">
                                                <p class="population_estimate">Population Estimate</p>
                                                <div class="population_estimate_box" ng-model="selectedOption_8">
                                                    <p class="hidden select_8"><strong>{{selectedOption_8.value}}</strong></p>
                                                    <p class="total">{{scotland_total()}}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div ng-switch-when="Northern Ireland Health And Social Services Board">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <form>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="pull-left">Health Board</label>
                                            <select ui-select2 class="form-control select_2nd"  ng-model="selectedOption_9" ng-options="data as data.displayName for data in ireland_data">
                                                <option selected value>Select</option>
                                            </select>
                                            <div class="population_estimate_wrapper">
                                                <p class="population_estimate">Population Estimate</p>
                                                <div class="population_estimate_box" ng-model="selectedOption_9">
                                                    <p class="hidden select_9"><strong>{{selectedOption_9.value}}</strong></p>
                                                    <p class="total">{{ireland_total()}}</p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Then we have a hide show function, that will hide the above section, and show code that is currently hidden.

HTML2:

```
<div class="main_container_wrapper">
        <div class="main_container">
            <div class="budget_row odd bg_lines_1">
                <p class="blue size15"><strong>Primary non-familial hypercholesterolaemia or mixed dyslipidaemia</strong></p>
                <div class="row_left">
                    <p class="grey size13"><strong>Total catchment population</strong></p>
                </div>
                <div class="row_right text-center">
                    <p class="number_box">{{totals_test}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So basically, whatever html is in the class="total" should be dumped into a $scope.totals_test variable. What I want to do, is if i go back to the previos page, and change the html, have angular update that when i go forward again. (its all on one page, just showing and hiding different sections)

Comment: what is the second section we didn't understand little explain?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-show for show hide instead of calling jquery, jquery is not under digest of AngularJS

also use something like this: $scope.number.show... if you use hirerichy like this, it will reflect in controller.. i dont know why, but it works

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand fully what you're asking, but I believe you're looking for the following View and Controller.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="!showParagraph">
<p>{{number()}}</p>
<button ng-click="show">Click Me</button
</div>

<div class="example_2" ng-if="showParagraph">
<p ng-bind="number()"></p>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.show= function() {
      $scope.showParagraph = true;
};

$scope.number = function() {
      5 * 5
};
```